# How to select from inner state

Tags: angular5, ngrx

I want to select inner part of the state ‘homepage_banner’  And I’m getting:

```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'homepage_banner' of undefined
    at MapSubscriber.generalData [as project] (generalReducer.ts:37)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:69)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:83)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:83)
    at ReplaySubject._subscribe (ReplaySubject.js:46)
    at ReplaySubject._trySubscribe (Observable.js:171)
    at ReplaySubject._trySubscribe (Subject.js:87)
    at ReplaySubject.subscribe (Observable.js:159)
    at Observable._subscribe (Observable.js:229)
```

**When I’m selecting the modules from state there is not problem only when I try to get to inner level**
here is my state:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tq5Wz.png)

this is the module interface:

```
  export interface IAppGeneral {
     modules:{
        [key:string]: { 
            html:{
                data: {
                    [key:string]:string;
                }
            }
            css:{
                data: {
                    [key:string]:string;
                }
            }
        }

    }


}
```

and this is the reducer:

```
  import {createSelector,createFeatureSelector} from '@ngrx/store';
import * as generalActions from './../actions/general.actions';

import {  IAppGeneral } from '../model/generalModel';


export interface IAppState {
    appGeneralData:  IAppGeneral ;
}

const initialState: IAppState = {
    appGeneralData:[]
};


export function appGeneralReducer(state = initialState, action:generalActions.Actions): IAppState {

    switch (action.type) {
          case generalActions.GET_GENERAL_APP_DATA_SUCCESS:{
                         // console.log('reducerGeneral',action.payload)
                          return Object.assign( {}, state, action.payload )

                //  return {...state,appGeneralData:action.payload}     
         }

        default:  {
            return state;

        }

   }

}


 export const  generalData = (state: IAppState) => state.appGeneralData['modules']['homepage_banner']
```

Comment: Please don't post code as images. It is not readable my mashines - just to name one of many reasons why this is bad

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use images to convey textual information. [Edit] your question to replace them with the respective code. Additionally, questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Without this, your question is off-topic and liable to be closed. Please construct a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include it.